# Unsure of which version of selenium I need to use to test a web application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using the firefox plugin version of Selenium so far to enter information into a form and submit it.  The form gets posted to a database and the info shows up on another URL that I check.  I need to be able to check the info I submitted in the original form against the info that shows up on the second page the "info submitted" page.

Does the firefox plugin version of selenium support a way of storing the information for the fields I submit to the initial form as variables so I can check those values against the "submitted info" page later?

I am new to selenium in general.

Answer (score 0):

I found following [FireFox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/stored-variables-viewer-seleni/) to check variables you use in test, so it seems it's possible with Selenium IDE.

On the other hand, I would recommend using Selenium WebDriver as it is more up to date and allow you much more than IDE due to everything what programming languages like Java or C# provides.

In your case, you could for example, open first page in fist browser tab, post form, then move to second tab with another page and check values correctness. Easy to implement and quite effective.

You can find numerous tutorials on the internet, or you can check my own tutorial which I started to post recently under my own project - [Test Automation 101](http://testautomation.pl/selenium-en/).